# Fallo al recorrer los datos de una BBDD con bucle while PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero comprobar que, efectivamente, estoy leyendo los datos que quiero de la BBDD MySQL con PHP. Este es el código:

```
    <?php

    $queryWS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
    $lecturaWS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $queryWS);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($lecturaWS)){
        $datosPK_WS=$row; 
    }
    var_dump($datosPK_WS);
```

Básicamente tengo una duda:

Esa misma query en la consola de MySQL me saca todos los ids de la tabla. Sin embargo, en PHP, cuando lo ejecuto en XAMPP sólo me saca los dos primeros ids de la tabla y no comprendo por qué, debería de sacarme todos los de la tabla ya que tengo el bucle puesto. No sé en qué fallo.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No estás duplicando la pregunta?

Comment: No, la otra me la cerraron porque decían que ya estaba respondida, efectivamente aprendí de la respuesta, pero no lo suficiente para ver en qué estoy fallando.

Comment: En tu código siempre sobreescribes la variable $datosPK_WS. Al final solo te mostrará los datos de la última linea. Puedes añadir [] en la variable, para que se trate como un array, de esa manera debería contenerte todos los datos. Cambia por $datosPK_WS[] y nos cuentas...

Comment: Entonces para evitar te cierren está de nuevo debes explicar mejor el problema por qué al momento luce como un clon de la otra

Comment: ¿No se entiende bien el problema que tengo en esta?

Comment: @Sergio sigue la recomendación de Jakala

Comment: Ya me ha funcionado, gracias a lo que me ha comentado Jakala. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Entonces responde la pregunta para no dejarla abierta

Comment: Ah vale, no sabía eso :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
    $queryMS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
    $lecturaMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $queryMS);

    while($row=odbc_fetch_array($lecturaMS)){
        $datosPK_MS[]=$row; 
    }

    var_dump($datosPK_MS);
```

De esta forma, me mete los datos en el array y no me los sobreescribe.